# Using Html.Begin form and FormMethod.Get resulting in form posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, orchardcms, html-helper

Using a Razor cshtml file in an MVC/Orchard application.

Form area reads as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get, new { area = "Area.area"})) {
    Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)

    <div class="actions">
    @Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "OtherAction", "Controller", new { area = "Area.area"}, new { @class = "button"})
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<form action="/Location/URL" method="post">
    <!---Editor Fields etc-->
    <div class="actions">
        <a class="button" href="/Location/OtherURL">OtherAction</a>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, this form is assigned the POSTmethod, which as far as I can tell is contrary to the use of FormMethod.Get in the FormMethod argument of Html.BeginForm.

One things I did notice whilst testing out another form (the real form is much, much longer so I inserted a very small one to see if the syntax/behaviour checked out) was the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get, new {area = "Area.area"})) {
    <button value="submit">Test</button>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get, new { area = "Area.area"})) {
    Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)

    <div class="actions">
    @Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "OtherAction", "Controller", new { area = "Area.area"}, new { @class = "button"})
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

This resulted in the following:

```
<form action="/Location/URL" method="post">
    <button value="submit">Test</button>
    <form action="/Location/URL" area="Area.area" method="get">
        <!---Editor Fields etc-->
        <div class="actions">
            <a class="button" href="/Location/OtherURL">OtherAction</a>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</form>
```

So this appears to have made the first form a POST and the second one a GET but has put the second form inside of the first one.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting area as a property on the form. It looks as though you are using an incorrect overload on the forms as I imagine you want area to be included in the Route Values as opposed to in the Html Properties

Comment: Although I don't think that would explain the nesting forms- do you have a form element in a parent view?

Comment: Turns out yes, there was. Thank you.